# ¿Cómo borrar una tabla si existe y crearla otra vez para pruebas?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Quiero recrear una tabla en *SQL*... Estoy trabajando en *SQLite*, pero de ser posible quisiera que funcione también en *Oracle* para poder hacer pruebas.

Es decir:

1. Comprobar si existe la tabla.
2. Si existe borro la tabla
3. Vuelvo a crear la tabla pero con los campos que yo quiero.

Código *SQL*:

```
DROP TABLE mi_tabla IF EXISTS mi_tabla;
CREATE TABLE mi_tabla (
    "Texto_1"   TEXT,
    "Texto_2"   TEXT
);
```

El error que me sale es el siguiente:

> Resultado: near "IF": syntax error
>   En la línea 1:
>   DROP TABLE mi_tabla IF

¿Es posible usar una tabla de pruebas sin ser creada? o de lo contrario ¿Se puede recrear una tabla que puede o no existir?

Comment: mi_tabla es el nombre correcto y "mi tabla" no contiene el guion bajo, corrige ese error.

Comment: @MiguelZarate Hice el cambio pero sigue saliendo el mismo error. Lo del if no sé cómo hacerlo en verdad.

Comment: @MiguelZarate Bien, ¿Pero hay alguna manera de borrarla solo si existe?

Comment: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mi_tabla;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La sentencia es así:

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mi_tabla
```

Comment: Si pones la parte de crearla estaría completa.

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], aunque correcta tu respuesta carece de explicación lo cual la hace lucir de baja calidad, recuerda no solo nos debe ser clara a nosotros sino al resto de comunidad que la consulta

Answer (score 3):

Podrías usar simplemente:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mi_tabla
```

**pero lo que deseas es verificar si existe y en base a esto eliminarla y volver a construir su estructura.**

Lo puedes realizar eliminando la tabla si existe y posteriormente, verificando si no existe, creas la tabla y su estructura nuevamente:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mi_tabla;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mi_tabla (
    "Texto_1"   TEXT,
    "Texto_2"   TEXT
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Complementando con la respuesta de *Manuel Panizzo*... Luego de eliminarla puedo agregar valores y mostrar la tabla, de la siguiente manera:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mi_tabla;
CREATE TABLE mi_tabla (
    "Texto_1"   TEXT,
    "Texto_2"   TEXT
);
INSERT INTO mi_tabla
VALUES ('cero', 'uno');
SELECT * from mi_tabla;
```

De esta manera puedo seguir haciendo pruebas. Si borro la tabla luego de hacer `SELECT`, muestra el resultado por unos milisegundos y lo deja de mostrar.

Comment: Solo querías borrarla y volver a crearla? :-| Plop!

Comment: @Jorgesys Además tenía planeado insertar valores y mostrarlos, pero me había complicado en la parte de borrar la tabla.

Comment: ya quedó revisa mi respuesta.